# Django Rest Framework serializing nested data

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework, drf-queryset

I am trying to serialize data in this Serializer but I am always getting the output `{}`

**Here is my serializer:**

```
class RelationshipSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    user = UserSerializer(read_only=True)
    related_user = UserSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = models.Relationship
        fields = (
            'user',
            'related_user',
        )
```

**Here is my view:**

```
related_user_id = body["related_user"]
related_user = models.User.objects.get(id=related_user_id)

user = self.get_object()

user_serializer = serializers.UserSerializer(user).data
related_user_serializer = serializers.UserSerializer(related_user).data

# user_serializer and related_user_serializer return valid data.

data = {"user": user_serializer, "related_user": related_user_serializer}

serializer = serializers.RelationshipSerializer(data=data)

serializer.is_valid() # valid

return Response(serializer.data)
```

I am getting the id of `related_user` from post request then getting the queryset of the actual object, and `user` is the id passed in the url: `user/{1}/`. I then serialize each user and create a dictionary to pass to `RelationshipSerializer`. The serializer returns valid but the response is `{}`, what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
class RelationshipSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = models.Relationship
        fields = (
            'user',
            'related_user',
        )
```

views.py

```
user = self.get_object()
data = {"user": user.id, "related_user": request.data["related_user"]}

serializer = serializers.RelationshipSerializer(data=data)
if serializer.is_vaild():
    serializer.save()
return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: I want to serialize the dictionary because the object doesnt exist yet. So i cant go `objects.get`. After i serialize it I am going to save it

Comment: Try user = self.request.user

Comment: @Ykh having only the id wouldn't work since user and related_user should have nested values of UserSerializer not only Id

Comment: @FeedGit, self.request.user just returns `Bad Request`, `self.get_object()` seems to work fine in my case, it serializes correctly and everything